# Define matrix as variable in multi-staged yaml pipeline

Tags: azure-devops, yaml, azure-pipelines

I'm creating a multi-staged Azure DevOps (yaml) pipeline that uses multiple references to other templates. As you can see in my pipeline below I have to supply the same matrix to my `build-client-steps.yml` and `distribute-client-steps.yml` files. This matrix is used for the strategy of my pipeline.

Is there a way to declare this matrix as a variable of my `azure-pipelines.yml` file?

```
stages:
- stage: build
  displayName: Build & validate
  jobs:
    - template: pipelines/templates/build-client-steps.yml
      parameters:
        matrix:
          base-ios-prod:
            app: string
            artifact: string
            variant: string
            os: ios
            distribution: string
          base-android-prod:
            app: string
            artifact: string
            variant: string
            os: android
            distribution: string
        keystore_password: '$(keystore_password)'
        keystore_alias: '$(keystore_alias)'
        APPLE_CERTIFICATE_SIGNING_IDENTITY: '$(APPLE_CERTIFICATE_SIGNING_IDENTITY)'
        APPLE_PROV_PROFILE_UUID: '$(APPLE_PROV_PROFILE_UUID)'
        teamId: '$(teamId)'
        P12Password: '$(P12Password)'         
    - template: pipelines/templates/build-server-steps.yml
    - template: pipelines/templates/build-infra-steps.yml
    - template: pipelines/templates/build-sap-steps.yml
- stage: prepareBase
  displayName: Prepare base infra
  dependsOn: build
  jobs:
    - template: pipelines/templates/deploy-infra-jobs.yml
      parameters:
        parameterFile: string
        resourceGroup: string
- stage: deployBase
  displayName: Deploy base
  dependsOn: prepareBase
  jobs:
    - template: pipelines/templates/deploy-server-jobs.yml
      parameters:
        resourceGroup: string
- stage: activateBase
  displayName: Activate base
  dependsOn: deployBase
  jobs:
    - template: pipelines/templates/swap-app-jobs.yml
      parameters:
        parameterFile: string
        resourceGroup: string
    - template: pipelines/templates/distribute-client-jobs.yml
      parameters:
        matrix:
          base-ios-prod:
            app: string
            artifact: string
            variant: string
            os: ios
            distribution: string
          base-android-prod:
            app: string
            artifact: string
            variant: string
            os: android
            distribution: string
```

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't seem to be possible to do this in pure YAML, but the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/phases?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#multi-job-configuration) indicates it is possible to interpret a matrix strategy configuration from a JSON serialised string.

The example provided demonstrates the use of a step to output a variable containing a potentially dynamic JSON encoded object, which is then consumed in a subsequent step. I have discovered that it is also possible to consume in the same way a static variable containing a JSON encoded matrix. The YAML multi-line text formatting feature with `>` makes defining such a JSON string reasonably convenient. For example:

```
variables:
  targets: >
    {
      base-ios-prod:
      {
        app: 'string',
        artifact: 'string',
        variant: 'string',
        os: 'ios',
        distribution: 'string'
      },
      base-android-prod:
      {
        app: 'string',
        artifact: 'string',
        variant: 'string',
        os: 'android',
        distribution: 'string'
      }
    }

stages:
- stage: build
  displayName: Build
  jobs:
    - job: buildSrc
      displayName: Build source
      strategy:
        matrix: $[ variables.targets ]
      ...

- stage: deploy
  displayName: Deploy
  jobs:
    - job: deployApp
      displayName: Deploy application
      strategy:
        matrix: $[ variables.targets ]
      ...
```

Comment: Thanks, this was almost perfect for my use case where the matrix is a stringify JSON object in a variable coming from a variable group. 

The only change I had to make was to use the format `$[ variables['variable-name'] ]` to reference the variable correctly

Comment: i had to use $[ parameters.variable_name ] in my nested template, while always having used ${{ parameters.variable_name }} for parameters in other places.

Comment: The json string is missing a lot of quotes, e.g. 'base-ios-prod' etc. This is also shown in the documentation that you have linked to.

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a way to declare this matrix as a variable of my
>   azure-pipelines.yml file?

For this issue ,as far as I know, this is not feasible in the yaml pipeline.There is a statement in this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml%2Cbatch#expansion-of-variables) : Since variables are expanded at the beginning of a job, you cannot use them in a strategy. So even if you can define a matrix as a variable, you can't reference it in a strategy.

In addition,your `build-client-steps.yml` and `distribute-client-steps.yml` files should be Job templates, then you should be able to write the matrix into the job template. In this way, you only need to reference the job template in the `azure-pipelines.yml` file.